# c# Excel, the provider 'microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0' is not registered

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, visual-studio, oledb

I am working on a c# project where I need the user to open an Excel file and insert the data in an SQL server database. The problem is that using this connection string

`("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")`

during the opening of the connection I get

> the provider 'microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0' is not registered

exception, which is odd because I worked with an Access Database and used the same connection string. The Access Database Engine is installed on my PC and I even compiled at x86, am I missing something?

Comment: Show your ODBC provider list

Answer (score 0):

The reasons are as follows:

1. When accessing the .xlsx file with SQL SERVER, you must use
   provider 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' to implement.
2. First install AccessDatabaseEngine.exe.
   Download path: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7554F536-8C28-4598-9B72-EF94E038C891&displaylang=en
3. This provider can be seen in the database on 32-bit systems.
4. It cannot be seen in a 64-bit system, so you need to call
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe
   to execute the package.

solution:

1. Open IIS Manager.
2. Right-click the connection pool where the application is located.
3. Modify "Enable 32 as application" to true.

The code shown below may help you.

```
   Sqlconn sqlcon = new Sqlconn();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    string str_Excel_Path;

    private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Only one file can be opened------------------------------------------
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel file|*.xlsx";//Set the open file filter
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Open Excel file";//Set the title of the open file
        openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;//Allow multiple files to be selected
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)//Determine whether a file is selected
        {
            str_Excel_Path = openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString();//Get the selected file address
            textBox1.Text = str_Excel_Path;//Display the selected file address in textBox1
        }

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text != "")
        {
            string[] P_str_Names = textBox1.Text.Split(',');//Store all selected Excel file names
            string P_str_Name = "";//Store the traversed Excel file name
            List<string> P_list_SheetNames = new List<string>();//Create a generic collection object to store sheet names
            for (int i = 0; i < P_str_Names.Length; i++)//Iterate over all selected Excel file names
            {
                P_str_Name = P_str_Names[i];//The Excel file name traversed by the record

                P_list_SheetNames = GetSheetName(P_str_Name);//Get all sheet names in the Excel file

                for (int j = 0; j < P_list_SheetNames.Count; j++)//traverse all worksheets
                {
                    /* if (ckbox_Windows.Checked)//Log in to SQL Server with Windows authentication
                     //Export worksheet contents to SQL Server
                     {
                         ImportDataToSql(P_str_Name, P_list_SheetNames[j], "Data Source='" + txt_Server.Text + "';Initial Catalog='" + cbox_Server.Text + "';Integrated Security=True;");
                     }
                     else if (ckbox_SQL.Checked)//Log in to SQL Server with SQL Server authentication
                     {
                         ImportDataToSql(P_str_Name, P_list_SheetNames[j], "Data Source='" + txt_Server.Text + "'Database='" + cbox_Server.Text + "';Uid='" + txt_Name.Text + "';Pwd='" + txt_Pwd.Text + "';");
                     }*/

                    ImportDataToSql(P_str_Name, P_list_SheetNames[j], "Data source=localhost;Initial Catalog=student;User ID=sa;Password=123456");
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("All selected Excel sheets have been imported into SQL Server database!", "Prompt", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select the file to be imported into the database!");
        }
    }




    //Get all worksheet names in the Excel file
    private List<string> GetSheetName(string P_str_Name)
    {
        List<string> P_list_SheetName = new List<string>();//Create a generic collection object
                                                           //Connect to the Excel database
                                                           //OleDbConnection olecon = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + P_str_Name + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
        OleDbConnection olecon = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + P_str_Name + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=yes;IMEX=1;\"");
        olecon.Open();//Open database connection
        System.Data.DataTable DTable = olecon.GetSchema("Tables");//Create a table object
        DataTableReader DTReader = new DataTableReader(DTable);//Create table read object
        while (DTReader.Read())
        {
            string p_str_sName = DTReader["Table_Name"].ToString().Replace('$', ' ').Trim();//Record the worksheet name
            if (!P_list_SheetName.Contains(p_str_sName))//Determine whether the sheet name already exists in the generic collection
                P_list_SheetName.Add(p_str_sName);//Add the worksheet to the pan-collection
        }
        DTable = null;//Clear the table object
        DTReader = null;//Clear the table read object
        olecon.Close();//Close the database connection
        return P_list_Sheet
  }



    /* Import the content of the specified worksheet in Excel into the SQL Server database */
    public void ImportDataToSql(string p_str_Excel, string p_str_SheetName, string p_str_SqlCon)
    {
        DataSet myds = new DataSet();//Create a dataset object
        try
        {
            // get all data
            //string P_str_OledbCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + p_str_Excel + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
            string P_str_OledbCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + p_str_Excel + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=yes;IMEX=1;\"";
            OleDbConnection oledbcon = new OleDbConnection(P_str_OledbCon);//Create an Oledb database connection object
            string p_str_ExcelSql = "";//Record the Excel query statement to be executed
            OleDbDataAdapter oledbda = null;//Create an Oledb data bridge object
            p_str_ExcelSql = string.Format("select * from [{0}$]", p_str_SheetName);//Record the Excel query statement to be executed
            oledbda = new OleDbDataAdapter(p_str_ExcelSql, P_str_OledbCon);//Execute Excel query using data bridge
            oledbda.Fill(myds, p_str_SheetName);//Fill data
            //Define variables to record the SQL statement that creates the table
            string P_str_CreateSql = string.Format("create table {0}(", p_str_SheetName);
            foreach (DataColumn c in myds.Tables[0].Columns)//traverse all rows in the dataset
            {
                P_str_CreateSql += string.Format("[{0}]text,", c.ColumnName);//Create a field in the table
            }
            P_str_CreateSql = P_str_CreateSql + ")";//Improve the SQL statement for creating a table
            //Create SQL database connection object
            using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(p_str_SqlCon))
            {
                sqlcon.Open();//Open database connection
                SqlCommand sqlcmd = sqlcon.CreateCommand();//Create an execution command object
                sqlcmd.CommandText = P_str_CreateSql;//Specify the SQL data to be executed
                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();//Execute operation
                sqlcon.Close();//Close the database connection
            }
            using (SqlBulkCopy bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(p_str_SqlCon))//Import data with bcp
            {
                bcp.BatchSize = 100;//Number of rows per transfer
                bcp.DestinationTableName = p_str_SheetName;//Define the destination table
                bcp.WriteToServer(myds.Tables[0]);//Write data to SQL server data table
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("SQL Server database already exists" + p_str_SheetName + "Table!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }
```

Sqlconn code:

```
    // private static string constr = "server=(local);Initial Catalog=D_total;Integrated Security=True";
       private static string constr = "Data source=localhost;Initial Catalog=student;User ID=sa;Password=123456";
    // private static string constr = "Data Source =192.168.1.201;Initial Catalog=D_total23 ;User Id=sa;Password=123";
    public DataTable f1()
        {
            string A = "select name from master..sysdatabases";//Query this database information
            return Only_Table1(A);
        }
        public DataTable Only_Table1(string exec)
        {
            System.Data.DataTable dt_jdl = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        con.Open();
                    }
                    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open || con.State == ConnectionState.Connecting)
                    {
                        SqlDataAdapter sda2 = new SqlDataAdapter(exec, con);//All by writing stored procedures
                        DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
                        sda2.Fill(ds2, "cxq");
                        dt_jdl = ds2.Tables["cxq"];
                        sda2.Dispose();
                        ds2.Dispose();
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
                return dt_jdl;
            }
            catch (Exception EX)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    

}
```

Run the project:

[image]

Click the OK button to select the xml file from the folder. Click the import button to import the file into the database.